# Cannot Access Base Files with LibreOffice 5.1.3

Tags: libreoffice, database

I'm new to Ubuntu, just around two months. I have a problem with LibreOffice version 5.1.3 (Base): I cannot access my Base files (.odb).

```
General error. General error input / output.
```

Can somebody provide some assistance?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
rm ~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/basic/dialog.xlc
rm ~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/basic/script.xlc
touch ~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/basic/dialog.xlc
touch ~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/basic/script.xlc
```